# Is there an Emacs Lisp API for Python interaction?

Tags: python, api, elisp

Something convenient like

```
(python-command-to-string &rest COMMANDS)
```

and the output from the Python interpreter is returned.

For example

```
(python-command-to-string
    "import jedi"
    "print(
jedi.Script(
code=\"[].append(0)\"
).infer(line=1, column=4)[0].full_name
)")
```

will return `"builtins.list.append"`.

Using temporary .py files can get the job done but I'd love to have a reusable, common approach.

Comment: On which operating system are you using `emacs` ?

Comment: I am using a Linux distribution.

Comment: I have seen many people used temporary files: write to a temp ".py" file then run it, but is there a common library for all of us?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64629596/edit) your question to improve it. You could be interested by something similar to [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) perhaps used thru [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), so writing that for Emacs should be easy (since it is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)...)

Comment: You might be interested in [tag:pymacs]: https://github.com/dgentry/Pymacs

Answer (score 1):

Ugly but kinda works.

```lisp
(defun python-command-to-string (&rest COMMANDS)
       "Use shell to call python."
       (shell-command-to-string
        (concat "python -c \"" (string-join COMMANDS "\n") "\"")))

(python-command-to-string
 "import numpy as np"
 "print(np.arange(6))"
 "print('blah blah')"
 "print('{}'.format(3))"
 )
```

Now there is the problem with using double quotes inside python code. I guess there is no harm with "single quotes only" constraints when invoking this function. Just don't upset the shell with stuff like `${}`.